# efficient way of equations from table

Tags: python

I have the following table shown in the figure with the first few entries shown below:

| n | m | equation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | dP-41 |
| 1 | 3 | 2dP-28 |
| 2 | 1 | -35 |
| etc |  |  |

[Formulas for suppression of harmonics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZEYU.png)

I would like to code this up in python such that I can specify a m and n and dP (delta Power) and it will spit out the suppression.

Other than doing a big if then statement, is there a more efficient / pythonic way of doing this?

(this for some RF engineering to calculate spurious responses from mixers: [paper here](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/articles/wj-tech-notes/predicting-intermod-suppression-double-balanced-mixers-v10-4.pdf)

Comment: One way is to write a small function to replace e. g. "2dP" by "2*dP" to make it a valid Python expression and then use "eval" to calculate the result. "eval" is dangerous but if the possible expressions are under your control it should be ok.

Comment: Were you helped by the provided answer? If so, please consider accepting it (click on the check mark) so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries to the rescue!

Note that each of the harmonic suppression equations are linear: there is a coefficient, the variable (`dP`), and a constant -- all equations follow the form `y = mx + b`.

Therefore, we can implement one generic `suppression()` function which accepts `dP` and a coefficient (the `m` in `mx + b`) and a constant (the `+ b`).

Then, you can use tuples to map `(n, m)` pairs to their corresponding suppression equation:

```py
def suppression(dP, *, coef, const):
    return coef * dP + const


LO_RF = {(1, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": 0},
         (1, 2): {"coef": 1, "const": -41},
         (1, 3): {"coef": 2, "const": -28},
         (2, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": -35},
         (2, 2): {"coef": 1, "const": -39},
         (2, 3): {"coef": 2, "const": -44},
         (3, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": -10},
         (3, 2): {"coef": 1, "const": -32},
         (3, 3): {"coef": 2, "const": -18},
         (4, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": -35},
         (4, 2): {"coef": 1, "const": -39},
         (5, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": -14},
         (5, 3): {"coef": 2, "const": -14},
         (6, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": -35},
         (6, 2): {"coef": 1, "const": -39},
         (7, 1): {"coef": 0, "const": -17},
         (7, 3): {"coef": 2, "const": -11}}


def calculate_suppression(*, n, m, dP):
    try:
        return suppression(dP, **LO_RF[(n, m)])
    except KeyError:
        print("Invalid (n, m) pair!")
```

Demo:

```py
In [3]: calculate_suppression(n=3, m=2, dP=21)
Out[3]: -11
```

Note that `*` in a function's signature denotes that arguments after it are keyword-only. This is not necessary, but helps prevent users from putting their arguments in the wrong order -- with keyword-only arguments, order doesn't matter because the value of each argument must be assigned by name (basically, it's very difficult to give an incorrect value for `n` if you are forced to type `n = ...`).

The `suppression()` function does require the keyword args, but it's possible to remove this limitation if you want -- you'll just need to modify some code.